# R create column in dataframe value name of dataframe

Tags: r, loops

I have a list of dataframes (these are spatial dataframes) named for example "map_g1_r1_airport", "map_g1_r1_hotel", "map_g1_r2_bank", "map_g1_r2_market"

These are elements that were digitized from several maps. The maps were originally called "map_g1_r1", "map_g1_r2".

I am trying to add a column to each dataframe with the name of the original map using a loop.

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
map_g1_r1_airport$mapid<-map_g1_r1
```

```
With the loop (Unfortunately this does not do what I intend to do. Instead it simply creates a "content" field in the Values board.):
```

```
list_df<-c("map_g1_r1_airport", "map_g1_r1_hotel", "map_g1_r2_bank", "map_g1_r2_market")
```

```
    for (df in 1:length(list_df)){
      paste(list_df[df],"$mapid<-", 
                    print(content<-gsub("(.*)_.*","\\1", 
                    c(paste(list_df[df]))),sep=""), 
                    quote=FALSE)}
```

Any help is most welcome!

Here is one example of the data before change:

```
structure(list(id = c(1, 2, 3), Name = structure(c(1L, 3L, 4L
), .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"
), class = "factor"), Year = structure(c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_), .Label = character(0), class = "factor"), geometry = structure(list(
    structure(c(41.4086152370865, 2.44718243982123), class = c("XY", 
    "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(45.3852740543083, -4.31103098867136
    ), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(38.4200314592624, 
    -6.96113884231683), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg"))), class = c("sfc_POINT", 
"sfc"), precision = 0, bbox = structure(c(xmin = 41.4086152370865, 
ymin = 2.31103098867136, xmax = 45.4200314592624, ymax = -4.44718243982123
), class = "bbox"), crs = structure(list(epsg = NA_integer_, 
    proj4string = NA_character_), class = "crs"), n_empty = 0L)), sf_column = "geometry", agr = structure(c(id = NA_integer_, 
Name = NA_integer_, Year = NA_integer_), .Label = c("constant", 
"aggregate", "identity"), class = "factor"), row.names = c(NA, 
3L), class = c("sf", "data.frame"))
```

This is what I would like to get (with the mapid **map_g1_r1**):

```
structure(list(id = c(1, 2, 3), Name = structure(c(1L, 3L, 4L
), .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"
), class = "factor"), Year = structure(c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_), .Label = character(0), class = "factor"), geometry = structure(list(
    structure(c(41.4086152370865, 2.44718243982123), class = c("XY", 
    "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(45.3852740543083, -4.31103098867136
    ), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(38.4200314592624, 
    -6.96113884231683), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg"))), class = c("sfc_POINT", 
"sfc"), precision = 0, bbox = structure(c(xmin = 41.4086152370865, 
ymin = 2.31103098867136, xmax = 45.4200314592624, ymax = -4.44718243982123
), class = "bbox"), crs = structure(list(epsg = NA_integer_, 
    proj4string = NA_character_), class = "crs"), n_empty = 0L), 
    mapid = c("map_g1_r1", "map_g1_r1", "map_g1_r1")), sf_column = "geometry", agr = structure(c(id = NA_integer_, 
Name = NA_integer_, Year = NA_integer_, mapid = NA_integer_), .Label = c("constant", 
"aggregate", "identity"), class = "factor"), row.names = c(NA, 
3L), class = c("sf", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Could you use `dput` to give us an example of `df`?

Comment: @RonakShah, map_g1_r1_airport has three column (id/city/size) and two rows. map_g1_r2_bank has four column (id/city/size/branch) and only one row.

Comment: @RonakShah I added the necessary information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all the individual dataframes in a list using `mget` and add a new column with their name using `mutate`.

Using `tidyverse` functions you can do this as :

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

list_df<-c("map_g1_r1_airport", "map_g1_r1_hotel", "map_g1_r2_bank", "map_g1_r2_market")
tmp <- mget(list_df)

result <- imap(tmp, ~.x %>% mutate(map_id = .y))
```

`result` will have all changed dataframes in a list, if you want these changes to reflect in the original object you can use `list2env`.

```
list2env(result, .GlobalEnv)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve that even without a loop.

I would first start by creating a list with the names you want to see in each spatial data.frame. I assume they are derived from the names of the list.

```
mapid = names(list_df)
```

following that you can employ `mapply` to use a function that takes
the first element of a list (or vector) and the first element of another list/vector. Them it moves on and apply the same function to the second elements of each vector. It is essentially a multiple input version of `lapply`.

The function we will give to `mapply` is `cbind` which creates takes takes two data.frames and joins them by column. In this case one data.frame will be your spatial object and the other will be a vector with one single element: the current map name. `cbind` will naturally convert this name to a 1-column data.frame and repeat the name to match the number of rows in the spatial object.

```
final = mapply(cbind, list_df, mapid)
```

I haven't tested it, but it should work.

Comment: Dear @JMenezes, unfortunately I have 44 mapid and 177 list_df. I have not been able to implement your solution even though it looks promising.